# add image from folder outside of the project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to show some images that are outside of the project folder of rails, is it possible that rails can take them? or must they necessarily be inside the assets folder?

Comment: I suppose the best solution is to have your media inside the project directory. Either in app folder or public folder ! Otherwise you need a lot of effort handling the assets pipeline ! BTW take a look at this :
https://learn.co/lessons/images-and-the-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 1):

1. Upload image to cloud and use HTTP path.
2. If you let image outside the folder of rails, you will have some trouble about asset-pipeline.